# Show full name only to intended recipient in e-mail to many

Tags: php, html-email

I've included multiple recipients emails based on the variables collected from my form so it only shows their email and no one else's upon receiving a confirmation email:

```
$headers = 'From: company@company.com' . "\r\n"
           . "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
           . "BCC: " . $_POST['email2'] . ', ' . $_POST['email3'] . ', ' . $_POST['email4']  . "\r\n";
```

How would I go about displaying multiple names that are associated with the relevant email in the HTML email without other recipients seeing other names? (Below would obviously show all names to all recipients which is what I don't want).

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<p>Dear '. $name1 . ' . $name2 . '. $name3 . '. $name4 . ',</p>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 3-rd side libraries, instead of creating new ones:

- [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
- [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

You can also see how this is done there: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php

Look at the `preSend` and `AddrAppend` methods.

Comment: +1 For SwiftMailer. An example would make this more +1 worthy!

Answer (score 0):

Send the email to yourself and set recipients as bcc.

Have a look at the documentation: [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

You can add recipients to bcc with *additional_headers*

A little tip at the end: Always escape your POST-fields.
A spam bot could easily use your form to send spam to millions of people and your ip will soon be blocked from anti-spam networks. And then no mail you send will get to the recipient.

EDIT: 
Ok well: I do not know any way to achieve your desired result.
You have to send the mail personalized to everyone itself. Just use a for or foreach loop.

Comment: Although informative and appreciated, I have already both of those things set up as shown above, (the escape POST fields also, although not included here). I was after displaying variables in the HTML email related to the recipients email, i.e $_POST['email2'] goes to  $name2, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry that i misunderstood your question. Edited my answer.